# множественное удаление с помощью триггера на удаление

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE
  Authors
FROM
  Authors
INNER JOIN
  Books_Authors
ON
  Authors.kod=Books_Authors.Author_Kod
INNER JOIN
  Books
ON
  Books_Authors.Book_Kod=Books.kod
WHERE
  Books.Count = 0
```

Есть код, который удаляет всех авторов, у количество книг которых равно 0.
Как переделать код, чтобы удаляло с помощью тригера mssql?

Вот мои попытки:

```
alter trigger deleteBooks
    ON Authors
    FOR DELETE 
    AS
    DELETE Authors from Authors 
    INNER JOIN Books_Authors ON Authors.kod=Books_Authors.Author_Kod 
    INNER JOIN Books on Books_Authors.Book_Kod=Books.kod
    WHERE Books.Count = 0
GO
```

Comment: А зачем это вообще делать при удалении из таблицы авторов. Если бы так было бы можно то у вас бы триггер зациклился, при удалении одной записи авторов будет вызван триггер, который начнет удалять авторов, но при этом опять же будет вызван триггер удаления авторов и так далее

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ZeroBookDelete
    ON Books
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE Authors
        WHERE Kod IN (SELECT Authors_Kod
                        FROM Books_Authors
                        WHERE Book_Kod IN (SELECT Kod
                                            FROM INSERTED
                                            WHERE Count = 0))
END
GO
```

Это просто аналог вашего первого запроса в виде триггера. Некоторых моментов он не решает, допустим, нарушения целостности данных. При таком удалении у вас для Authors_Kod в таблице Books_Authors не будет соответствующей записи в таблице Authors. Язык не поворачивается назвать это поле внешним ключом, так как в случае внешнего ключа ваш запрос не работал бы из-за попытки нарушения целостности данных. Также не ясно, что будет, если потом кто то изменит поле Count в таблице Books на значение большее нуля: Автор уже удален, а книги опять есть.